# Android app crashes onDestroy while a location service is running

Tags: java, android, service, location, main-activity

I wrote an app that starts a location service, the service gets an Address using Intent, and pops a notification when the location is inside and outside a pre-defined radius.
The problem is when i'm trying to destroy the MainAvtivity. I want the service to keep alive, but when i destroy the App, it crashes.

My code:

LocationService.java

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private boolean inRange = false;
private boolean isNotificationPosted = false;
private DatabaseHelper db;
private ReportItem item;
private float lastKnownDistance;
private Location chosenLocation;

private static final long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 10000;
private static final float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 10;
private static final int RADIUS = 100;
private static final float INITIAL_DISTANCE = 1000;

private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        float distance = location.distanceTo(chosenLocation);

        if(!isNotificationPosted)
        {
            if (lastKnownDistance > distance) {

                //Entering workplace radius
                if (distance < RADIUS && !inRange) {
                    Log.i("Service", "in range with notification");

                    inRange = true;
                    item = new ReportItem();
                    makeNotification();
                    isNotificationPosted = true;

                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            if (lastKnownDistance < distance) {

                //Leaving workplace radius
                if (distance > RADIUS && inRange) { //out of range
                    Log.i("Service", "out of range with notification");

                    inRange = false;
                    item.setExit(new Date());
                    db.createReport(item);
                    makeNotification();
                    isNotificationPosted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        lastKnownDistance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Please turn on your location services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(final Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    final Address chosenAddress = intent.getParcelableExtra("chosen address");
    chosenLocation = setLatLong(chosenAddress.getLongitude(), chosenAddress.getLatitude());
    lastKnownDistance = INITIAL_DISTANCE;
    Log.i("Service", "lase known location, distance: " + Float.toString(lastKnownDistance));

    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME,
            LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE,
            mLocationListener
    );

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    this.mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this.mLocationListener);

}
```

Starting the service from MainActivity:

```
serviceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class);
//selected address is from type Address
serviceIntent.putExtra("chosen address", selectedAddress);
saveIntentIntoSharedPreferences(serviceIntent);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Any idea what might cause the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: post the error log!

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

I removed the Address object from the Intent that delivered to the service and it suddenly working perfectly.
I've got my Address object from the sharedPreferences inside the Service.